# \tcolorbox with Equation and \footnotetext

Tags: equations, footnotes, tcolorbox

I need help on is with `\tcolorbox`.

I have two equations but I need only one `\footnotetext`.

How to proceed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=CORREÇÃO]
    A equação da corrente no emissor de $Q_1$ e $Q_2$, com $V_{BE} = V_B - V_E$     
    
    \begin{align*}
    \tcbhighmath{ I_{E_1} = \dfrac{I_S}{\infty} \, e^{\dfrac{(V_{B_1} - V_E)}{V_t}}   }      \qquad
    \tcbhighmath{ I_{E_2} = \dfrac{I_S}{\infty} \, e^{\dfrac{(V_{B_2} - V_E)}{V_t}}   }
    \footnotetext{Video Aula 3C, Slide 17, 9:50 minutos}
    \end{align*}
    
    Dividindo $I_{E_1}$ por $I_{E_2}$ e vice-versa:
    
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Image 1 is the current result. Image 2 is what I need.

[image]

[image]

You have no idea how much I appreciate all of this.

And thank you very much for your cooperation.

Comment: Please provide your `MWE` full format, in an error free format from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Take the `\footnotetext` outside of the `align*` environment.  But,as Mady notes, you need to provide us with a full working example to fully understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, remove the `\footnotetext` macro from the `align*` environment, because it performs a multiple-pass, grabbing the `\footnotetext` on each pass.

Please let me know if I misunderstand your need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=CORREÇÃO]
    A equação da corrente no emissor de $Q_1$ e $Q_2$, com $V_{BE} = V_B - V_E$     
    
    \begin{align*}
    \tcbhighmath{ I_{E_1} = \dfrac{I_S}{\infty} \, e^{\dfrac{(V_{B_1} - V_E)}{V_t}}   }      \qquad
    \tcbhighmath{ I_{E_2} = \dfrac{I_S}{\infty} \, e^{\dfrac{(V_{B_2} - V_E)}{V_t}}   }
    \end{align*}
    \footnotetext{Video Aula 3C, Slide 17, 9:50 minutos}
    
    Dividindo $I_{E_1}$ por $I_{E_2}$ e vice-versa:
    
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your goal (I'm trying to understand the red arrows in the OP figures) is to place the footnote in the tcolorbox itself, I would instead fudge it, as I do below using stacks.  In the left box, I use a `\tiny` footnote size, and in the right box, I use `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=CORREÇÃO]
    A equação da corrente no emissor de $Q_1$ e $Q_2$, com $V_{BE} = V_B - V_E$     
    
    \begin{align*}
    \tcbhighmath{ \Shortunderstack[l]{%
    I_{E_1} = \dfrac{I_S}{\infty} \, e^{\dfrac{(V_{B_1} - V_E)}{V_t}}\\\\
    \rule{4em}{.6pt}\\\text{\tiny Video Aula 3C, Slide 17, 9:50 minutos}}} 
    \qquad
    \tcbhighmath{ \Shortunderstack[l]{%
    I_{E_2} = \dfrac{I_S}{\infty} \, e^{\dfrac{(V_{B_2} - V_E)}{V_t}}\\\\
    \rule{4em}{.6pt}\\\text{\scriptsize Video Aula 3C, Slide 17,}\\
    \text{\scriptsize 9:50 minutos}}} 
    \end{align*}
    
    Dividindo $I_{E_1}$ por $I_{E_2}$ e vice-versa:
    
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]